# why does screen rotates from landscape to portrait on 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I just created a dvd to try ubuntu 17.10 before installing.  It goes well untill the screen rotates 90 degrees right or left for no apparent reason.  Any idea on how to fix this problem??

Comment: After quitting on the issue of rotating screen on 17.10, I came back on ASK UBUNTU for help, and bingo!  The solution is so simple and right on front of our eyes, the little icon showing a rotating screen can be locked just by pressing on it.   Thanks a lot.